# In PHP i want to filter my data by date in my database date column(timestamp type)

Tags: php, mysql

The problem is i want to fetch data on particular date.

This is my form

```
<form>
<label>Enter the date</label>
    <input type="date" name="date">
  </form>
```

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
     $date = $_POST['date'];
     $query = "select * from user_date where date ='$date' ";
     }
```

In database date column(timestamp type) if i write this code this code is not work because i don't pass time.If i pass time this code is work.

Comment: What is the value of `$date` variable ?

Comment: This is value of $date= 2018-10-05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your code is open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/2469308) related attacks. Please learn to use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Now, the problem here  is that `$date` value is date only (eg: `2018-11-10`), instead of datetime; while your table's `date` column is of datetime (`Timestamp` data type).

You need to use [`Date()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to convert your `date` column to date only, for checking

```
$query = "select * from user_date 
          where DATE(date) = '" . $date . "'";
```

Also, do read: [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/2469308)